# @JsonIgnoreProperties usage for both known and unknown properties

Tags: java, json, jackson

My current annotation for ignoring the known properties for a JPA entity is:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler","created","updated","createdBy","lastUpdatedBy"})
```

In addition to ignoring these class properties, I would also like to ignore any unknown properties that the server receives. I know the alone way to ignore the unknown properties by the following annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
```

But not sure how to add this to my current annotation given above. I tried multiple methods ås below but none seem to work and I could not find an example online for this scenario.

Any example or leads on documentation would also help.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin yes it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Set [`ignoreUnknown`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#ignoreUnknown()) to `true` and define the names of properties to ignore in the [`value`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#value()) element:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true, 
                      value = {"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", "created"})
```

### How does it work?

Have a look at this quote from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html) (highlight is mine):

> In its simplest form, an annotation looks like the following:
>
> ```
> @Entity
> ```
>
> The at sign character (`@`) indicates to the compiler that what follows is an annotation. In the following example, the annotation's name is `Override`:
>
> ```
> @Override
> void mySuperMethod() { ... }
> ```
>
> The annotation can include *elements*, which can be named or unnamed, and there are values for those elements:
>
> ```
> @Author(name = "Benjamin Franklin", date = "3/27/2003")
> class MyClass() { ... }
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> @SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked")
> void myMethod() { ... }
> ```
>
> **If there is just one element named `value`, then the name can be omitted**, as in:
>
> ```
> @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
> void myMethod() { ... }
> ```

### Other way to handle unknown properties

To ignore unknown properties, you also could do:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Comment: Why isn't `ignoreUnknown=false` working? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052262/how-do-i-enable-strict-validation-of-json-jackson-requestbody-in-spring-boot

Comment: @Chloe `false` is the default value https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html#ignoreUnknown()